# How to retrieve sections of a form I accidently deleted (including the surveyors responses)?

Tags: google-forms

First time using Google Forms and I was so impressed!  It was doing everything I needed for research on a book I am writing.  However, Thursday night... on my phone looking at some responses I accidentally deleted the questions (and the responses).  I could not find them anywhere and re-created the document but I am now missing my first 40 responses.  The updated survey still includes the #40 replies at the top but the answers are not there.  Can it be recovered?

Comment: https://forms.gle/24W6AvC5C3vzpDhw9

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Is your form connected to a Google spreadsheet?

Comment: No.  First time user and not google doc savy.  Is there any hope for me?